# Restrict visibility of published APIS to self in the publisher portal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Not able to figure out a way to restrict editing rights of published APIs only to self - the creator/provider of the API. Ex: Let us say there are 1000 creators, one way is to create 1000 roles and do user-role mapping, but this is not viable. And for that reason, looking for some dynamic way to restrict the listing in a way that publisher portal shows (with editing rights) only those APIs that are published by the logged in publisher.

Comment: In APIM you manage set of APIs developed by set of API developers in a given org. But if you need to have access control over APIs, one option is to go with tenant mode. But i would recommend creating tenants per departments. - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/multitenancy/managing-tenants/#adding-a-new-tenant

Comment: Appreciate you sparing time to answer. But this wouldn't work for me. My use case is 1000+users, self registered individuals, having a tenant created per user is not really a viable option. I see you are tech lead at WSO2, i would be really thankful if you can help suggest something better, like some config (or even an option to write custom code, but how and where) that can restrict view/editing rights only with the creator/provider/publisher.

Comment: For me this requirement is a rare case. The publisher should be accessed by few set of people.

Comment: Fair enough and appreciate the response. But for my use case it is the key requirement. Any further help you can do on this in official or unofficial capacity, even if it requires touching the code.